# Check if at least 1 node value matches certain pattern

Tags: string, xpath, compare

I'm trying to check for a value in an element contain certain pattern.
For example I have some of the following elements:

```xml
    <message>
      <locnr>A001</locnr>
      <locnr>K301</locnr>
      <locnr>Z310</locnr>
      <locnr>B311</locnr>
    </message>
```

I want to find if there's **at least 1 locnr element** that:

- starts with ***'A' / 'C'***
- and the second character is either ***'0' / '1' / '2'***.

In the sample case above then the file the message passes the test because of the locnr with the value 'A001'.

Answer (score 2):

If your XPath processor supports XPath 2.0, use a regular expression for this.

```
/message[locnr[matches(., '^[AC][012]')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following XPath expression should do what you want:

```
message[substring(locnr,1,1)='A' or substring(locnr,1,1)='C']
       [substring(locnr,2,1)="0" or substring(locnr,2,1)="1" or substring(locnr,2,1)="2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
//message
[
  count(locnr[starts-with(text(),'A') or starts-with(locnr/text(),'C')])>0 
  and 
      substring(locnr/text(),2,1) = '0' 
    or 
      substring(locnr/text(),2,1) = '1' 
    or 
      substring(locnr/text(),2,1) = '2'
]
```

Answer (score -2):

In my recent experience with XPath and XML documents I found that the XPath expressions were more designed to help locate specific nodes as opposed to analyze the values held within them. Sure you can filter the nodes returned based on the values but I believe(someone correct me if I'm wrong) that it's limited to simple equality or greater/less than for numeric values. This is done with a statement like:

/bookstore/book[price>35.00]

which is straight from the XPath syntax page on W3 schools and would return the book elements that have price children whose value is more than 35.

If I was in your position I would likely use XPath to just get all the locnr elements with the XPath simply "locnr" and then run a loop through the returned node list. For each node you can get the value of the string in two ways that I've found. If you know the element is a leaf then .text will work but if it might not be then watch out because .text returns all the values of the node AND its descendants. The alternative is to access the nodeValue of the first child of the node. Something like:

currentNode.childNodes[0].nodeValue

And just use string methods to extract the characters you are interested in, with conditionals for your patterns.